Use of the phrase "to where"
An example might be:  "We need to apply enough coats of paint to where no one will be able to see the color underneath it."
Is this phrase improper?

Welcome to ELU. The accepted practice is that a post’s title should express the question that’s being asked. I invite you to edit your title, which at present is an assertion about a friend. This would not only make it clearer exactly what you want to know, but also make it more useful for other learners in future.

"to where" doesn't sound right, because the relative pronoun "where" is supposed to tell about a place, but in your sentence it is not.
So, you should probably put a noun before "where". For example:
We need to apply enough coats of paint to places/areas/spots where no one will be able to see the color underneath it.

That's not the intended meaning.

The phrase is short for "the point where". For example, here's Shia LaBeouf using it at 0:30 or so in his odd motivational speech video:

You should get to the point where anyone else would quit, and you're not gonna stop there!

(Though you're not asking this, for the sake of any other learners, your example means "to apply so many coats of point that no one will be able to see the color underneath it".)
This expression is not particularly elegant — some might argue that it's already a slight corruption of "the point at which" — and you wouldn't expect it in a throne speech or academic journal article, but it's pretty common in regular conversation.
The condensed version "to where" hasn't gained full acceptance yet, and it sounds very elliptical; it's kind of an odd word pairing. Still, it would be surprising if a native speaker hadn't heard it at least once in their life in the last ten years or so, in my opinion. It sounds to my ear a bit between colloquial and jargon-y, but a lot of people talk that way without raising anyone's hackles.

I've definitely heard competent naive American English speakers use this phrase before, and didn't think anything of it. However, the only sort-of authoritative source I can find mentioning it on the internet calls it an error (for... some reason ) https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/25/to-where/ . So, I guess I would call it informal English, based on that. Although, I feel like I've also read it in formal writing, so maybe that source is just wrong. In fact, I feel like I've heard and read it in non-dialectical, formal speech and text enough to where I'm comfortable saying it's perfectly licit.

I think you mean competent native.

Ah, indeed, I mistyped. They are also naive, though ;)
